# Jquery live preview plugin on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experimenting with jquery live preview plugin wich shows preview of websites on hover in tooltip. You can check out the plug in here: https://github.com/alanphoon/jquery-live-preview

I was wondering if it's possible to set up that plug in to be activated on click of button instead of default hover function?

I'm trying to set this up here but I did not succeeded: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/YARYp/

first one is default link on hover and second one is button on which I wanna apply this plug in but on click.

I've tried `.on("click",function...` and `.click` but it failed..

code looks like this:

html:

```
<a href="http://www.bing.com" target="_blank" class="livepreview">Hover over to preview, click to link!</a>
<br />
<button class="clickpreview">Preview</button>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".livepreview").livePreview({
                viewWidth: 400,  
                viewHeight: 300,

                });
        });
```

any suggestion or help is welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".livepreview").livePreview({
        viewWidth: 400,  
        viewHeight: 300,

    });

    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#link").trigger("mouseenter");
    });
});
```

> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YARYp/3/)

Comment: you've answered firstm pratcitally the same as @Anton so points for you... thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.trigger('mouseover');`

```
$('.clickpreview').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.livepreview').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YARYp/1/)