# form preview before submit like github comments from

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i see in `github comments form` write and preview tab. in `preview` tab github print write text for preview comments brfore send/submit text. how to `work/method` github preview comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to textarea Or Comments preview using `jQuery` plugin:

- [Textarea Preview](https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/jquery-textareaPreview)
- [Wordpress Comments preview Plugin](https://github.com/wp-plugins/jquery-comment-preview/)
- [jQuery Live Preview](https://github.com/Haacked/jQuery-Live-Preview)

also, u can see this example :

- [jQuery Comment Preview](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/jquery-live-preview.php)
- [Jquery live preview plugin on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824316/jquery-live-preview-plugin-on-click)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need javascript to take the value you've entered in the textarea, parse it into the format needed, and then render it in the other window.

GitHub uses a custom version of Markdown, so you can use javascript markdown parsers